# How do I select all rows from my database that have a value that is part of a certain string?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a loop that is producing a string like `$sku = MAR-9-870-2-L`. I have a database that is a list of "skusearchquery" that often look like skusearchquery = MAR-9. I am trying to do a search for all rows of the database that have a skusearchquery contained inside the string $sku.

I know the code below doesn't work because `MAR-9-870-20-L` is NOT LIKE `MAR-9-870` because `MAR-9-870` doesn't contain the longer string, so I'm wondering how I can say: if the row value skusearchquery matches part of the string `MAR-9-870-20-L`, then select it.

```
$search = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM skusearch WHERE skusearchquery LIKE '%$sku%'");
```

Comment: Please add the database structure of your table

Comment: I rewrote the question for clarity.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the `LOCATE()` function:

```
$search=mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT * FROM skusearch WHERE LOCATE(`skusearchquery`,'$sku'");
```

...if this tests positively, you should take tadman's advice and protect your query.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, that your **searchquery** field can have smaller part of **sku** then you can try below query to get those results as well

```
$search = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM skusearch WHERE skusearchquery LIKE '%$sku%'" or '$sku'  like  concat('%',skusearchquery,'%');
```

Also make sure to protect your queries from sql injection as suggested by @tadman.